# SQLite: Optimal PAGE_SIZE

Tags: performance, sqlite, optimization, pragma, page-size

I read that the default PAGE_SIZE value of 1024 in SQLite has been chosen merely for compatiblity between different platforms and operatings systems.

Since my app runs only on Windows systems, would it be safe to increase it to a larger value (like 4096) or could it have any unwanted side-effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only drawback is that an ill-adjusted page-size could make your database slower. Ultimately, page_size optimization will depend on four factors:

- platform
- schema
- data
- queries (i.e. usage)

Test and compare, that's the only way.

Comment: From [phiresky](https://phiresky.github.io/blog/2020/sqlite-performance-tuning/): Increasing the page_size `improved performance and db size a lot for me in one project, but it is probably only useful if you are storing somewhat large blobs in your database and might not be good for other projects where rows are small. For writing queries SQLite will always only replace whole pages, so this increases the overhead of write queries.` 

What is a good reason to change (increase or decrease) the page_size? How does this affect execution speed?

Comment: According to [Using SQLite](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/using-sqlite/9781449394592/re194.html) `If the datatype driver indicates that the native I/O block of the filesystem is larger, that larger value will be used up to the maximum default size, which is normally set to 8192.`
From this [comment](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/issues/4325#issuecomment-761907495) `recommended to tune filesystem & database to match the pagesize of the db to the most efficient for your fs`  Example: using ZFS set recordsize to 64k, and set the SQLITE pagesize to 64k as well.`